# Using eachDirMatch to skip .svn folders

Tags: groovy

I'm writing a program which needs to traverse a set of directories. Tried to use the following code:

> file.eachDirMatch(/.*[^.svn]/){
>      //some code here 
>   }

But that ended up match none of my directories. I realize this boils down figuring out the right regex *hang head in shame* but even after revisiting some Java Regular Expression documentation I thought this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
/^(?!\.svn).*/
```

(This assumes that your language's regex flavor supports negative lookaheads.)

Comment: Try a basic `/.*/` then and make sure that you're actually matching against *something*  - `.*` should match anything passed in, so it may not be the regex at fault.

Comment: /.*/ did not work but ~".*" did. The Groovy documentation made it seem like i could use the /-notation. Tried ~".*[^svn]" and that did the trick but I don't like the fact that it will match a directories other than ".svn"

Comment: Okay finally figures out what i was doing wrong. Your regex did work correctly I just needed to add the "~" before either a String or / notation of a pattern. Thanks for the help

Comment: can anyone explain why that is? Just ran into the same problem. Why would I have to add the tilde to pass a regexp?

Comment: @Matthias: [Look at http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_regular_expression_operators]. The tilde is a Groovy operator to create a Pattern instance, and the slashes are simply delimiting the string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any expression as matcher, not just regular expression:

```
file.eachDirMatch({ new File(it).name != ".svn" }) { dir -> println(dir.getPath()) }
```

Comment: Not sure that you need the `new File(it)` constructor. I think `it` is already a File object.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Amber answer, whole thing looks like

```
file.eachDirMatch(~/^(?!\.svn).*/) { /* some code here */ }
```

For example to filter out all those hidden dirs in current directory you can use

```
file('.').eachDirMatch(~/^(?!\.).*/) { dir ->
    println dir.getPath()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To the uninitiated (to regex) this looks like gibberish. Why not just do

```
directories = []
file.eachDir() { File directory -> 
    if (directory.name != ".svn") {
      directories << directory
    }
}
```

Or if you want to ignore all hidden files do:

```
directories = []
file.eachDir() { File directory -> 
    if (!directory.startsWith(".")) {
      directories << directory
    }
}
```

One-liners are great and all, but now it's easy to read (and maintain presumably)